# Optimize counting values in huge pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a really huge dataframe (3.5+ million raws). It describes in game events for many games. It has 20+ columns, but to be short let's say I need only 2 of them: game_id and event. So, the game_id is just an id and event can be like 10 different types. I need to count event of some type for each game. But for some games desired event can never happen.
For example:

```
    game_id event
0   1       my_event
1   1       my_event
2   1       some_event
3   1       some_event
4   2       some_event
5   2       some_event
6   2       some_event
7   3       my_event
8   3       some_event
```

And after I want to get:

```
    game_id num_of_my_event
0   1       2
1   2       0
2   3       1
```

So `df[df.event=='my_event'].groupby('game_id').size()` doesn't work because in some cases there is no event. But it worked fine and really fast for events which are exist in all games.

I've tried next thing:

```
event_dic = {i:len(events_df[(events_df.game_id == i) & (events_df.event == 'my_event')])
             for i in set(events_df.game_id.values)}
```

But it works so slow! Can you help me with more optimized way to do it?

Comment: df.groupby(['game_id','event']).size()

Comment: As I said, it doesn't count zeros for some games there are no such event type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unstack your groupby and use fill_value to put zeros in.

```
df.groupby(['game_id','event']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

Output

```
game_id  event     
1        my_event      2
         some_event    2
2        my_event      0
         some_event    3
3        my_event      1
         some_event    1
dtype: int64
```

If you want to get a specific one, try this:

```
df.groupby(['game_id','event']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)['my_event'].reset_index(name='num_my_event')
```

Output

```
    game_id num_my_event
 0  1       2
 1  2       0
 2  3       1
```

Comment: And how get from that series only my_event types? Cause `events_df[events_df.event=='my_event'].groupby(['game_id','event']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()` 
still doesn't count, your way works, but has information about other events.

Comment: Updated to add more options